# What is the standardized format for Scrabble match annotations?

Tags: scrabble

I have seen graphical walk-throughs before of past Scrabble matches.  Watching the masters play is a great way to learn.  Is there a widely accepted manner in which to annotate games?  If so, is there anywhere a low-level description of such an annotation system?  I have looked at Go in ages passed and I know there is a very detailed specification for annotating Go matches.  I am looking for something similar with Scrabble.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found one example of an annotation method used.  The [gcg](http://www.poslfit.com/scrabble/gcg/) format seems to be allowed on Cross-Tables.

This format consists of a number of lines which can be divided into 2 classes:

1. Events
2. Pragmata

The former are moves by players, passes, exchanges, challenges, and end of game events (penalties or bonuses for tiles remaining at the end of the game).  They start with the character `>`

The latter are comments on the game, player names, the contents of player racks and a bunch of other options for future expansion or which have been made obsolete.  They start with the character `#`

The development of .gcg can be traced back to John Chew in August 2000.  I am not aware of its significance in the world of Scrabble nor of any competing annotation schemes which may be in place, particularly in Scrabble which is not TWL and especially for non-English Scrabble

Comment: Please summarize the important information in that link. Sites change, and links go bad; if that happens, your answer won't be useful anymore. Summarize the important bits so that your answer can remain relevant forever.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured out the format used by WordBiz to store annotated games.  To get the annotation for one of your recent 10 games which you are observing, you choose Save under the File menu and the annotated game will appear in the log file (whatever file you have chosen to be your log, log.txt in WordBiz directory by default).

The format itself I cannot find documented but I can describe it:

Line 1 is by example: Internet Scrabble Club, 08:Sep:13, dictionary: TWL, time: 10 0 rated, noescape: ON, challenge: VOID

So you have date, dictionary, time, rated, and challenge method most importantly.

Line 2 has each player along with their rating and initial rack.  Player 1 in the left side, Player 2 is right side

Line 3 and on to the second to last row are the actual plays.  You get the round, play, the score for that play and the new rack for each player in each round.  Cumulative score is not stated on each line.  CHANGE is shown for an exchange along with the new rack. PAS is shown for a pass, including for the end of game event where player 1 has run out of tiles and therefore player 2 gets no move for the last round.

The last line shows the game score for each player.  It does not show ratings adjustments.

As far as I can tell, comments are not stored in this format like they are in gcg.  I do not know what the name of this format is, but it appears quite likely that it is a custom format meant especially for WordBiz.